# DJANGO Generic View Cannot Find Attribute 'as_view'

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app where I have the following code:

[app]/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),  
...
]
```

[app]/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Chat
from .models import Message
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required()
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "trout_line/index.html"
    context_object_name = 'latest_chat_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Chat.objects.filter(start_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-start_date')[:5]
```

and a template at `[app]/templates/[app]/index.html`.

When I run the server I receive the following message.

```
... path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'), 
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'
```

I thought I followed the tutorial closely, but obviously I am missing something.  Any help would be appreciated.

I am running Python 3.6 and Django 2.1.2 on Ubuntu 16

Comment: how did you import the `IndexView` in your `urls.py`?

Comment: you can do like this in your urls.py

from .views import *
path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),